# how to unit test a REST client for an unreliable server?

Tags: python, unit-testing, rest

I'm making a Python-based REST client for a 3rd party service that's still under development. The issue is to test/verify that the client will work under ALL kinds of scenarios. Including incorrect responses.

The client uses the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make the remote REST calls (mostly GET and POST). And for unit testing, I'm thinking of employing the [HTTPretty](http://falcao.it/HTTPretty/) module to simulate/mock the server responses.

The problem is how to deal with the sheer number of possible test cases. Consider the following made-up API;

REQUEST (GET) = `http://example.com/new_api?param1=34&param2=hello`

RESPONSE = `{"value1":34,"value2":"a string"}`

I find myself needing to write unit test cases for the following scenarios -

- client sending correct number of parameters
- client sending incorrect parameter values
- client missing a parameter
- server's correct responses for above scenarios
- server not sending back all the required values
- server mixing up value parameters (returning a string instead of a number)
- server sending back HTML instead of JSON
- ... etc

The intent behind all this extensive testing is to help identify where an error could originate from. i.e. is it my client that's having an issue, or the 3rd party server?

Does anyone know of a good way to organize a Python test suite to accommodate these scenarios? Writing unit test functions feels like it will become a never-ending task... :(

Answer (score 0):

That's the goal of unit testing is to test all the cases where you think, you might have to handle errors. On the other hand you do not need to test things which are already handled naturally by the system.

Note that HTTP is an application level protocol where the client always initiates the request and the server just responds. So what I mean by this, is that because you are developing the client you are not responsible of the server response. Your goal is just to sent the appropriate requests.

On the other hand, there are HTTP responses which might trigger behaviors on the client side. These you want to test. For example, the server answers a 301, and you want to test if your client does the right thing by initiating the next request, grabbing the `Location:` HTTP header value.

In the case of a REST API (aka hypertext driven), your client will parse the content of the HTTP responses and specifically the set of links and/or rel associated value. Based on these values, the client may make decisions or expose possible choices to the users. These you have to test.

If the server doesn't give the information **inside** the HTTP response for continuing your exploration on the client side, then it's not a REST API, but a perfectly valid HTTP API. Simple as that. It becomes even easier to test. Nothing much to do.